# Hidden app icon on iOS launcher

Tags: ios, xcode, enterprise-distribution

How can i hidden app icon on iOS, I develop App for Enterprise, there are two Apps，for some reason，I need to **hidden App A's icon form launcher**, make it only can be open in App B.

Because Apps will not distribution on App store, any private API can be used. Is there any way to achieve this？

Answer (score -1):

If you archive your application for enterprise distribution, you are asked to provide additional information in a manifest.plist:
[image]
The App URL is not really important, most of the time you just enter "https://"

But in the Display Image URL and Full Size Image URL your should provide a valid URL, which is resolvable by your clients to the app icon of your app.

This image will only be displayed until the app was successfully installed.

Comment: Thanks, but what i want is hidden the icon even app was installed, which makes it can not be opened from launcher.

Comment: Oh I see, then I missunderstood your initial request. Do you have the device, on which the app shall be installed next to you? Can you attach it to your Mac and open xCode. Here go to Window -> Devices. Select your iOS Device and see in the right panel on the bottom the console output of the device. When you do now select the app being installed. What logs do you see? Can you extend your question input with this output? :)